# Howto force umask 002 for all software?

Tags: filesystems, umask

I have added umask 002 to /etc/profile, but software like git and apache still sets files to 755 instead of 775. Is there a way to force umask 002 for all programs on a machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this can be done globally but tracking down the startup scripts for the relevant software and setting the umask there should do the trick.

Comment: I think I found at least some of the problem. I switched to zsh and then /etc/profile doesn't seem to get loaded. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Iain, I love your nomination remarks & was already 2 for 3 when I saw your "don't vote for me, vote for...".