# Setting umask /etc/apache2/envvar not working Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, umask

I am trying to set the default umask to `umask 002`.
I tried adding it to:

```
/etc/apache2/envvar
/etc/profile
```

But after restarting Apache it hasn't changed?
Still `0022`.
Where do I have to put it?

Thanks

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/166176/ways-to-set-umask-on-ubuntu-for-daemon-processes for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best place is the apache startup scripting in /etc/init.d/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

The best place is where you've put it, `/etc/apache2/envvar`, afaik

If you're using mod_dav, you may be looking at a bug in the Apache mod_dav module in 10.04 (2.2.14 apache2) so that all files are created with the wrong permissions. 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/540747

I added one line to /etc/cron.daily/apache2 to `chmod -R a+r /var/www/webdavblah` which happened to fix my particular problem.

*-pike

Comment: And as noted on that bug report, it has finally been fixed: "This bug was fixed in the package apache2 - 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.9". I have updated and yay it works !